# Timers differences between Win7 & Win10

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-7, mingw, windows-10

I have a application where I use the MinGW implementation of `gettimeofday` to achieve "precise" timing (~1ms precision) on Win7. It works fine.

However, when using the same code (and even the same *.exe) on Win10, the precision drops drastically to the famous 15.6ms precision, which is not enough for me.

Two questions:
- do you know what can be the root for such discrepancies? (is it a OS config/"features"?)
- how can I fix it ? or, better, is there a precise timer agnostic to the OS config?

NB: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` seems to have the same issue (at least it does show the 15.6ms limit on Win10).

Comment: 15.6 is the normal value, it is your Win7 install that was misbehaving.  Call timeBeginPeriod() or use QueryPerformanceCounter() to get sub-microsecond resolution.  QPF is best.

Comment: How can a "misbehaviour" perform better? Does this come from a configuration option?

Comment: Normal and "better" have opposing goals.  It is rough on power usage, you'll drain a laptop battery in a hurry.  Not configuration, usually a program or driver that calls timeBeginPeriod().  [Chrome is notorious for doing this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-does-windows-have-terrible-battery-life/).  Run powercfg -energy to find the troublemaker on Win7.

Comment: Oh, the power usage settings make sense from what I know of the various distinct computer configurations I have tested. Your combined comments answer all aspects of my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Hans Passant comments and additional tests on my side, here is a sounder answer:

The 15.6ms (1/64 second) limit is [well-known](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/0/2/3027D574-C433-412A-A8B6-5E0A75D5B237/Timer-Resolution.docx) on Windows and is the default behavior. It is possible to lower the limit (e.g. to 1ms, through a  call to `timeBeginPeriod()`) though we are not advise to do so, because this affects the global system timer resolution and the resulting [power consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590475/why-does-increasing-timer-resolution-via-timebeginperiod-impact-power-consumptio). For instance, [Chrome is notorious for doing this‌​](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-does-windows-have-terrible-battery-life/). Hence, due to the global aspect of the timer resolution, one may observe a 1ms precision without explicitly asking for, because of third party programs.

Besides, be aware that `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` does **not** have a valid behavior on windows (both in [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470315/odd-behaviour-using-chronohigh-resolution-clocknow) or MinGW context). So you cannot expect this interface to be a cross-platform solution, and the 15.625ms limit still applies.

Knowing that, how can we deal with it? Well, one can use the `timeBeginPeriod()` thing to increase precision of some timers but, again, we are not advise to do so: **it seems better to use `QueryPerformanceCounter()` (QPC)**, which is the primary API for native code  looking forward to [acquire high-resolution time stamps or measure time intervals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) according to Microsoft. Note that [GPC does count elapsed time (and not CPU cycles)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080908-00/?p=20963/). Here is a usage example:

```
LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

// Activity to be timed

QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;


//
// We now have the elapsed number of ticks, along with the
// number of ticks-per-second. We use these values
// to convert to the number of elapsed microseconds.
// To guard against loss-of-precision, we convert
// to microseconds *before* dividing by ticks-per-second.
//

ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
```

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx), QPC is also suitable in a multicore/multithread context, though it can be less precise/ambiguous:

> When you compare performance counter results that are acquired from different threads, consider values that differ by ± 1 tick to have an ambiguous ordering. If the time stamps are taken from the same thread, this ± 1 tick uncertainty doesn't apply. In this context, the term tick refers to a period of time equal to 1 ÷ (the frequency of the performance counter obtained from  `QueryPerformanceFrequency`).

As additional resources, MS also provides an [FAQ on how/why use QPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx#general_faq_about_qpc_and_tsc) and an explanation on [clock/timing in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx#AppendixA).