# Execution time is zero in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, time, execution

I have written one program to calculate the execution time of the function. I want to display the execution time of it. I am using chrono library and using the `high_precision_clock` function of it. But still I am getting runtime as 0.

```cpp
void primsCall(){
    Prims prm(vec, adjMatrix);
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    prm.formMST(vec, adjMatrix);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(stop-start);
    cout<<"Prim's Algorithm MST: (total cost: "<<prm.mstCost<<"; runtime: "<<duration.count()<< "ms)"<<endl;
    for(string entry : prm.path){
        cout<<entry<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

Also I have used different function of chrono:

```cpp
void kruskalSCall(){
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    Kruskal ksk(vec, adjMatrix);
    clock_t start, end;
    start = clock();
    ksk.formMST(vec);
    end = clock();
    double runtime = double(end - start);
    cout<<"Kruskal's Algorithm MST: (total cost: "<<ksk.kMstCost<<"; runtime: "<<runtime<< "ms)"<<endl;
    for(string entry : ksk.kPath){
        cout<<entry<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

But in both the cases my output is 0.

**Prim's Algorithm MST: (total cost: 15; runtime: 0ms)**
(1,3)
(3,6)
(6,4)
(3,2)
(2,5)

**Kruskal's Algorithm MST: (total cost: 15; runtime: 0ms)**
(1,3)
(4,6)
(2,5)
(3,6)
(2,3)

Please suggest me to calculate the time of execution.

Comment: Run it 1,000,000 times and then divide total time by 1,000,000 for example.

Comment: Are you on Windows by chance?  IIRC the `high_resolution_clock` on windows only has a resolution of 15ms.

Comment: @0x5453 according to [doc.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/chrono?view=msvc-160) it's nanosecond... so citation needed.

Comment: @Mgetz Searching for "windows 15.6ms" gives [quite](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40594587/3282436) [few](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/reference/energy-analysis-metrics-reference/timer-resolution.html) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36696780/3282436), but I ran a few tests locally with `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` and it seems to work fine - I guess the latest Windows implementation of `chrono` has ways to work around the constraints?

Comment: @0x5453 timers are not clocks. There is a huuuuge difference between tick rate and what [`FileTimeToSystemTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-filetimetosystemtime) (which is what chrono uses under the hood on windows. The tick rate is irrelevant here because they aren't interested in wake ups but wall time. Windows since windows 8 has supported dynamic tick anyways.