# usleep function is slow on Windows 10 compared to Windows 7

Tags: c, dev-c++, usleep

I made some programs in C using Dev C++ that use the `usleep` function, which prints characters individually slower or faster, set by a number I want:

```
void lyrics(char *s, unsigned ms_delay){
   unsigned usecs = ms_delay * 1000; /* 1000 microseconds per ms */
   for (; *s; s++) {
      putchar(*s);
      fflush(stdout);
      usleep(usecs);
   }
}
```

When I ran them on Windows 7 they were perfect and the times were respected.

On Windows 10, it just prints the characters very slowly, 1 being the fastest, but still way slower than it should.

I've tried running as an admin, compatibility mode, affinity to 1 CPU core but those don't seem to work, and I don't have much knowledge of C to try other methods.

And it's used here to print each character at a certain speed, 200ms each being the slowest:

```
lyrics("We are ", 150);
lyrics("flying ", 190);
lyrics("high\n\n", 200);
```

Am I missing something or is it a Windows 10 thing?

I also am using C and **not C++**. A lot of the functions recommended and linked to my previous post are for C++ and will not run under C and vice-versa.

**Edit**: Minimal example code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void lyrics(char *s, unsigned ms_delay){     
    unsigned usecs = ms_delay * 1000;    
    for (; *s; s++) {
        putchar(*s);       
        fflush(stdout);       
        usleep(usecs);    
    }
} 
       
main(){ 
    lyrics("\
DDDDDDDDD        CCCCCCCCC  XXX     XXX\n\
DDDDDDDDDD     CCCCCCCCC     XXX   XXX\n\
DDD    DDDD   CCCCC           XXX XXX\n\", 1);
}
```

**Edit 2:** I found something peculiar. My program is quite extensive because it prints lyrics at different speeds and prints graphics made with ASCII.

When printing at 1, supposedly 1ms per character, it prints very slowly on 10, but when it plays the lyrics, it's the same speed as in 7. I changed the minimal code to reflect what I found and the videos below.

I also made a YouTube video showcasing my program before, which ran under Win7, and made a new one under 10 to show the difference and hopefully illustrate the situation better:

[Under Win7](https://youtu.be/auTMFb1FaqQ?t=10) (normal)

[Under Win10](https://youtu.be/eBzk237SCGQ)

I've tried to individually print each line with a 1, but it does the same thing.

Comment: When you last posted, it said the opposite: that `usleep()` does nothing. It also suggested that for your time spans `Sleep()` would be appropriate. This will run under C.

Comment: Note that Windows API does not have a function called `usleep`.

Comment: usleep is not a standard C function. It does not exist on Windows. How your C compiler/library implements it is a mystery, but Windows has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's why I deleted the post, there was a lot of things to correct. Also, `Sleep()` will not work to print characters, and for me, it does seconds and not milliseconds as a "pause" function.
@n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I use Dev C++ with `<windows.h>`. I ran the original and recompiled programs but they still run different per OS, it's why I thought of it being a Win10 thing.

Comment: No: you are looking at the gcc function `sleep()` with lowercase **s**, which takes seconds argument. The Windows function `Sleep()` takes milliseconds. Neither of them output characters. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried, to demonstrate what isn't working properly. I don't have Windows 10 though, only Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: @WeatherVane It works fine on 7, problem is when playing on 10, it's slower. PS: I have no idea how to paste this properly, sorry.
`#include <stdio.h>


void lyrics(char *s, unsigned ms_delay){

   unsigned usecs = ms_delay * 1000;
   for (; *s; s++) {
      putchar(*s);
      fflush(stdout);
      usleep(usecs);
   }
}
main(){
lyrics("fast\n", 10);
lyrics("slow", 150);
}`

Comment: For `Sleep()` you would need `#include <windows.h>`. The  `usleep()` is Linux (Posix?) function: it is not in Standard C nor in Windows API.

Comment: This popular question is tagged C and Linux. [Is there an alternative sleep function in C to milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157209/is-there-an-alternative-sleep-function-in-c-to-milliseconds) Answers suggest `usleep()` and `nanosleep()`. The accepted answer says *"`usleep()` has since been deprecated and subsequently removed from POSIX; for new code, `nanosleep()` is preferred:"*

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Windows 10 with gcc 11.2.0 (x86_64-pc-msys build and x86_64-w64-mingw32 build). The program runs and all delays are perfectly reasonable. WHich compiler version are you using? (Dev-C++ is not a compiler, it is a program editor/IDE).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I am using TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

Comment: My gut tells me that [`timeBeginPeriod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) is involved in this.

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 is about eight years old. Perhaps you may want to update it.

Comment: Sleeping is not guaranteed to give precise timing. I bet Windows 10 has some "timer coalescing" feature that makes the computer sometimes sleep longer to save power.

Comment: @user253751 it's called [Dynamic Tick](https://superuser.com/q/1293337/241386) but I don't know how they handle the timer when the ticks are longer. [Timers differences between Win7 & Win10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36696780/995714)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I've updated it to 12.1 and there's no noticeable difference

Comment: No idea. Try using one of the system tracers to find out where it lags https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847745/systrace-for-windows and perhaps submit a bug report somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: this is due to the **default granularity of the scheduler** on Windows 10. Use **`timeBeginPeriod`** to **manually adjust the granularity** of a sleeping function.

---

I can reproduce the effect on Windows 10 (version 21H1) on my machine. The effect happens only when `usleep` is called. This comes from the **OS scheduler**.

Indeed, when `usleep` is called, the OS causes a [**context switch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/context-switches). The threads is put in a waiting state and the console should be awaken since it was waiting for data to be printed. When the console is done, then the OS can execute other *ready* tasks regarding the [priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities) of the task. A task is basically a thread of a process (typically the main one in your case). The Windows OS scheduler tends to [boost the priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/priority-boosts) of tasks doing IO operation. When a task do not sleep and is not blocked on anything (eg. lock, IO reads), the task is scheduled for a predefined time called *quantum* (before a context-switch happens). The quantum can change from one machine to another but it is typically about a dozen of millisecond (something like 5~20 ms).

Funny point: the effect does not happen when low-level system profiler are running so the Windows scheduler change its behaviour (note the target process and the console are left unchanged). As a result, it is hard to debug the scheduler behaviour (especially since its code is closed-source).

On my system, the quantum time appears to be about 16 ms. The waiting time of an `usleep` call is generally about 15 ms (it is variable and often 16 ms). This means the scheduler certainly waits for the end of a quantum for no reason by default. Note the process is not scheduled during this quantum. In fact, no core are being used.

While this strategy is beneficial to save energy, it causes applications to be less responsive. Whether this is a bug is debatable since the documentation do not give any guarantee about that. Additionally, **tasks spending nearly all its time to wait for a timer may deserve to be less responsive than others by default**.

The documentation of the `SleepEx` function which is called by `usleep` specifically states:

> After the sleep interval has passed, the thread is ready to run. Note that **a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately**. Consequently, the thread will not run **until some arbitrary time after the sleep interval elapses**, based upon the system "tick" frequency and the load factor from other processes. The system clock "ticks" at a constant rate. To increase the accuracy of the sleep interval, call the **`timeGetDevCaps`** function to determine the supported minimum timer resolution and the **`timeBeginPeriod`** function to set the timer resolution to its minimum.

Using **`timeBeginPeriod(1);`** solved this on my machine. The minimum resolution is 1 millisecond (in practice I get timings of 1~2 ms). By default, the scheduler was configured to wait for up to 20 minutes in the most pathological case.

Comment: `timeBeginPeriod(1);` doesn't work or is recognized by the compiler I'm using. I tried elsewhere but it would require C++ and that would break other functions in my program